# Can column descriptions for views be defined using DDL?

Tags: google-bigquery

Its possible to open a view definition in the console and add a description

[image: editing a view in the UI]

Is it possible to create descriptions using DDL? i.e. Can I define column descriptions using a CREATE VIEW statement?

Comment: Currently it's not possible to add field description in a view using ddl statement. This feature request has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/140373298). However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: I've discovered that its possible to create descriptions for view columns using the same terraform resource that creates the view https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table (its achieved by defining both the `view` block and the `schema` property). This is good news for us because this is the mechanism by which we create views.